# Text mining using SpaCyr, What can be done?

Tags: python, r, nlp, spacy, text-mining

Recently, I built a model that can detect passive voice in the records of a dataset using SpaCy dependency parsing, rule-based matcher, and nlp.pipe(). Here's [the code for the project](https://github.com/mitramir55/Text-mining-in-marketing/blob/master/exp8.ipynb) for more clarity.

Now, my question is, is there any way I can use Spacy matcher for this task in R using SpaCyr? I couldn't find any specific thing myself but I think there may be some ways I can construct something with a similar functionality myself.

I also could make use of *n_processes* parameter in nlp.pipe() in python, as the dataset I'm working with is quite large. So if anyone has any idea about this too I'd love to hear it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your 'passive rules' to logic based on R package rsyntax https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsyntax/index.html (https://github.com/vanatteveldt/rsyntax) - logic shown at https://github.com/vanatteveldt/rsyntax/blob/master/Querying_dependency_trees.pdf
It allows to use the output of the either udpipe or spacyr parsers to construct queries of your annotated text.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference! I went over the pdf but actually couldn't find anything that enabled me to have one optional dependency or relation in the text. Do you think such a thing can be achieved using query in R?

Comment: yes, have a look at the documentation of rsyntax, not just the pdf